# Select customer type based on top selling product

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i write a query that looks at customers thats has multiple products and inserts a customer "type: based on the top selling product. 
For example:

```
Customer Product Revenue 
123          A       2000     
123          B       500      
123          C       1000
```

I want to write a query that looks at customer '123' for example and calculates the top selling product and inserts a tag into customer type. In this case 'Customer Type' should be "A" because "A" its the top selling product.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.  I assume that "top selling" is referring to the revenue column.  If so, this is an aggregation, a join, and a `case`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when t.revenue = tt.revenue then 'A' end) as type
from t join
     (select customer, max(revenue) as maxr
      from t
      group by customer
     ) tt
     on t.customer = tt.customer;
```

Comment: this is that i was looking for. thanks for your quick help.